# Photos App in Simulator Not Working

Tags: ios, ios7, ios-simulator

So I'm running Xcode 5, with an iOS7.1 simulator. When I load the simulator and go to the photos app all that appears is this. Just a completely blank app. I know I have images saved on my simulator. However even if I didn't it should say no photos etc and their should be a tab bar present. I've tried resetting content settings. Any ideas?
[image]

EDIT: As well in my personal app, I have this. Although this is just something I would appreciate people to look over as I doubt it would effect an external built in app :)

```
-(IBAction)selectPicturePressed:(id)sender
{
//Open a UIImagePickerController to select the picture
UIImagePickerController *imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imgPicker.delegate = self;
imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

[self.navigationController presentViewController:imgPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo 
{

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

//Place the image in the imageview
self.imgToUpload.image = img;
}
```

Comment: How are you presenting your photo picker?

Comment: Well this is more specific for just the photos app. However I would appreciate if you could look at the code as well in my personal app. I'll add it as an additional bit in the question.

Comment: drag some images in simulator and save in photo album. then check. Your question seems like no image found in photos.

Comment: Tried that, safari loads up saying file does not exist. I then just went to google images and just saved them from their. No change :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all else fails, delete Xcode including Simulator, Instruments, etc.. Then go to Apples Developer Downloads https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action and find the latest version of Xcode. Reinstall and it should fix the Simulator photo app.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I shouldn't have made that comment - I just figured it out. For me at least for some reason I found a folder titled "7.1" in my OS X trash. Restoring it to ""~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/" fixed my simulator and now the photos app works perfectly. Still not sure what caused the issue though